# can't delete picture from folder after inserting it in ms-word using win32com

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I need to insert an image to word document and then delete it from the hard drive.

```
from win32com import client
import os
client.pythoncom.CoInitialize()
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open("C:\R1234.docx")
newShape = doc.Bookmarks("layout1").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\picture.png", False, True)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
os.remove("C:\picture.png")
```

Looks very simple but returns an error trying to remove the picture:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process: 'C:\picture.png'

Comment: Are you certain it isn't open anywhere else? Your code works fine for me and deletes the image after inserting it as expected.

Comment: Could it be that `word.Quit()` returns instantaneously while the action is possibly dispatched and performed in the background? Then you should first wait for the word process being terminated before attempting to remove the file.